# Ошибка cv2.imshow не выводит изображение с камеры

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, cv2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
    output_video_name="/home/xsvebmx/Desktop/cameraObjectDetec.mp4")
  File "/home/xsvebmx/Desktop/92.63.179.49/NNXTS/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pixellib/instance.py", line 494, in process_camera
    cv2.imshow(frame_name, output)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) /tmp/pip-install-t0s5dfhx/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1272: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'
```

Ubuntu 23.10

(venv) python 3.7.6

tensorflow / gpu 2.4.1

pixellib 0.6.1

opencv 4.8.1.78

**Code:**

```
import pixellib
from pixellib.instance import instance_segmentation
import cv2

segmentation_model = instance_segmentation()
segmentation_model.load_model('/home/xsvebmx/Desktop/92.63.179.49/NNXTS/mask_rcnn_coco.h5')

target_classes = segmentation_model.select_target_classes(person=True)

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

seg, result = segmentation_model.process_camera(cam, segment_target_classes=target_classes, show_bboxes=True,
                                                show_frames=True, extract_segmented_objects=True,
                                                save_extracted_objects=True, frame_name='frame', frames_per_second=25,
                                                output_video_name="/home/xsvebmx/Desktop/cameraObjectDetec.mp4")
```

Помогите пожалуйста :(
При запуске должно появляться окно с выводом камеры, где нейросеть веделила сеткой обьекты
[image: вроде этого но в реалтайм]
вроде этого но в реалтайм

[image: пример второй в реалтайме]

Я новичок в теме нейросетей, не судите строго если ошибка показалась вам абсурдной

Comment: Заголовок вопроса должен отражать суть. текст вопроса должен объяснять подробности.

Comment: Простите, я не особо умею составлять вопросы

Comment: а вы выполнили рекомендации, которые вам дали в сообщении об ошибке?

Comment: Неа, я понять не могу что надо делать, да я вижу сообщение, но я не понимаю что где билдить, поэтому и написал(